# Sequence contains no matching element scaffolding visual studio 2015

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, controller, scaffolding

I am using code first database first (MYSQL, ENTITYFRAMEWORK 6, VISUAL STUDIO 2015)
I am trying to add a controller using scaffolding from the model generated

But i get "there was an error running the selected code generator sequence contains no elements, Unable to retrieve metadata for ...; Sequence contains no matching element";

The model were generated successifully from the database but adding a controller for the specified model using scaffolding returns error.

***DataContex***

```
 using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;

public partial class Model1 : DbContext
{
    public Model1()
        : base("name=Model1")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<actor> actors { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<address> addresses { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<category> categories { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<city> cities { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<country> countries { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<customer> customers { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<film> films { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<film_actor> film_actor { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<film_category> film_category { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<film_text> film_text { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<inventory> inventories { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<language> languages { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<payment> payments { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<rental> rentals { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<staff> staffs { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<store> stores { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<actor>()
            .Property(e => e.first_name)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<actor>()
            .Property(e => e.last_name)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<actor>()
            .HasMany(e => e.film_actor)
            .WithRequired(e => e.actor)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<address>()
            .Property(e => e.address1)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<address>()
            .Property(e => e.address2)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<address>()
            .Property(e => e.district)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<address>()
            .Property(e => e.postal_code)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<address>()
            .Property(e => e.phone)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<address>()
            .HasMany(e => e.customers)
            .WithRequired(e => e.address)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<address>()
            .HasMany(e => e.staffs)
            .WithRequired(e => e.address)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<address>()
            .HasMany(e => e.stores)
            .WithRequired(e => e.address)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<category>()
            .Property(e => e.name)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<category>()
            .HasMany(e => e.film_category)
            .WithRequired(e => e.category)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<city>()
            .Property(e => e.city1)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<city>()
            .HasMany(e => e.addresses)
            .WithRequired(e => e.city)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<country>()
            .Property(e => e.country1)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<country>()
            .HasMany(e => e.cities)
            .WithRequired(e => e.country)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<customer>()
            .Property(e => e.first_name)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<customer>()
            .Property(e => e.last_name)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<customer>()
            .Property(e => e.email)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<customer>()
            .HasMany(e => e.payments)
            .WithRequired(e => e.customer)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<customer>()
            .HasMany(e => e.rentals)
            .WithRequired(e => e.customer)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<film>()
            .Property(e => e.title)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<film>()
            .Property(e => e.description)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<film>()
            .Property(e => e.rating)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<film>()
            .Property(e => e.special_features)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<film>()
            .HasMany(e => e.film_actor)
            .WithRequired(e => e.film)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<film>()
            .HasMany(e => e.film_category)
            .WithRequired(e => e.film)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<film>()
            .HasMany(e => e.inventories)
            .WithRequired(e => e.film)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<film_text>()
            .Property(e => e.title)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<film_text>()
            .Property(e => e.description)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<inventory>()
            .HasMany(e => e.rentals)
            .WithRequired(e => e.inventory)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<language>()
            .Property(e => e.name)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<language>()
            .HasMany(e => e.films)
            .WithRequired(e => e.language)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.language_id)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<language>()
            .HasMany(e => e.films1)
            .WithOptional(e => e.language1)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.original_language_id);

        modelBuilder.Entity<staff>()
            .Property(e => e.first_name)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<staff>()
            .Property(e => e.last_name)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<staff>()
            .Property(e => e.email)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<staff>()
            .Property(e => e.username)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<staff>()
            .Property(e => e.password)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<staff>()
            .HasMany(e => e.payments)
            .WithRequired(e => e.staff)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<staff>()
            .HasMany(e => e.rentals)
            .WithRequired(e => e.staff)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<staff>()
            .HasMany(e => e.stores)
            .WithRequired(e => e.staff)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.manager_staff_id)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<store>()
            .HasMany(e => e.customers)
            .WithRequired(e => e.store)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<store>()
            .HasMany(e => e.inventories)
            .WithRequired(e => e.store)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<store>()
            .HasMany(e => e.staffs)
            .WithRequired(e => e.store)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.store_id)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

***My model***

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;

[Table("sakila.actor")]
public partial class actor
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public actor()
    {
        film_actor = new HashSet<film_actor>();
    }

    [Key]
    [Column(TypeName = "usmallint")]
    public int actor_id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(45)]
    public string first_name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(45)]
    public string last_name { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "timestamp")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public DateTime last_update { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<film_actor> film_actor { get; set; }
}
```

Can anyone help solve this?

Comment: Can you please provide which plugins & tooling you're using? EF6.x, which version of Visual Studio 2015?

Comment: Mysql for visual studio connector 6.9.9, EF6 ,ASP.NET MVC 5

Comment: But when using sql server, I dont get the error. I think this has to do with mysql

Comment: I suggest you to provide model class generated from MySQL table in your question. Remove all `[Column(TypeName = "<somedatatype>"]` annotation attributes if exists, clean and rebuild it, then try adding new controller through scaffolding.

Comment: I have added model class sample and the datacontex class above @TetsuyaYamamoto

Comment: The first suspicious is `[Column(TypeName = "usmallint")]`, which unsigned smallint mapped as signed int (try remove this leaving only `KeyAttribute`, unsigned smallint may unsupported in EF context). Second, `[Column(TypeName = "timestamp")]` should be changed to `[TimeStamp]` or `[ConcurrencyCheck]` depending on timestamp column usage.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to the software i installed. It blocked all not allowed traffic network access.

Check if your have any traffic filter software in your system